# Eclipse bug on start up, how do I fix it?

Tags: eclipse, logging, startup

When i try to run Eclipse Neon, I get an error message saying "An Error has occurred. See the log file F:\path\to\workspace.metadata.log."

Upon viewing the log, I found this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.recommenders.models.rcp 1 9 2016-07-08 23:06:53.728
!MESSAGE The model index service was accessed either before it started or after it finished running.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.Logs$LogTraceException
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.Logs$LogTraceException.newTrace(Logs.java:381)
....
```

Any ideas what is causing this, and how I fix it? I tried using good old Google, but all I got was that it is a reported bug that has been fixed, yet I am still getting the problem? Reinstalling eclipse didn't fix the problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common issue. There are two fixes:

**#1**

```
X:\WhereWS_Is\Workspaces\name_of_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\
```

Here delete *`.snap`* file. Eclipse will start normally then.

If not solved then second fix is a bit Heavy as it deletes all preferences etc.

**#2**

```
X:\WhereWS_Is\Workspaces\name_of_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\
```

Here delete(not permanently) *`workspace`* file. After starting Eclipse, IDE will re generate this file after all setup, paste that file again to get all your preferences.

Both tried, both worked for me. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: There was no file named .snap, I tried this fix before but I could not find the file. Instead however, I just deleted the .metadata file entirely, and that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i reinstalled Eclipse, still the bug.
I reinstalled JDK, still the bug.
I deleted my workspace (backed up my projects first), created a new workspace and copied my projects into that, and the problem seems to have gone for now. I still don't understand what caused it exactly, but it is now fixed.